# Equivalent of slideToggle() for change() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Looking for the equivalent of slideToggle for my `.change()` functions in jQuery, `.slideUp();` and `.slideDown();` do not seem to work with jQuery 1.13.

The reason I am not using slideToggle is because it will toggle on each change.

Any suggestions?

example

https://jsfiddle.net/yw8h3em3/

so basically it just shows and hides instantly, I would like it to animate slide down on show() and animate slide up on hide()

Comment: you can use show and hide() methods

Comment: I am currently using those but they do not animate a slide up and down effect which is what I am also looking for, unless they pass parameters that create that effect, I was unable to find that information.

Comment: I meant in terms of the way it animates.

Comment: And does it works on other jquery version? And please provide relevant HTML markup/ CSS too. What about a jsFiddle?

Comment: Use `.show("slow");` and `.hide("slow")`

Comment: yeah i did that but that did not slide down or up, it slides from the left by default, any way to change this direction?

Comment: If you want fine control over how it shows and hides I would suggest using [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your using a low jQuery version the best way to do this is use CSS and jQuery together the below works great.. it is not perfect but its a good way for you to do what you need to do and you can change the code around as you wish, this was a simple example.

```js
//call function on load
test();
//call function on change
$('#test1').change(function() { test(); });

function test() {
    $('.cont').toggleClass('toggled'); 
}
```

```css
.cont {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px #CCC solid;
  background-color: #EEE;
  padding: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: height .3s linear, padding-top .3s linear, padding-bottom .3s linear, border-width .3s linear;
}
.toggled {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<li class="form-line" id="id_44">
   <select class="form-dropdown" style="width:150px" id="test1" name="test1" >
        <option value=""> Select Option </option>
        <option value="Yes"> Yes </option>
        <option value="No"> No </option>
   </select>
</li>

<div class="cont">Toggle this div</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/joshstevens19/0Lb4ks8L/

Comment: yes this will work for your jQuery version as that is all i am referencing.

Answer (score 1):

I have just updated your jsfiddle to include jquery version 1.11 and it works fine for that.

here is the updated link and code snippet

https://jsfiddle.net/yw8h3em3/3/

```
function test() {
    if ($('#test1').val() === 'No') {
        //test1 list
        $('#id_45').slideDown();
    } else {
        //test2 list
        $('#id_45').slideUp();
        $('#id_45').val("");
    }        
}
```